# Sql Server Job steps

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am dynamically adding steps to a Sql Server Agent Job, but I need to get the last step id to determine the next id in the sequence.  I cannot seem to find any built in sps that can give me this information.

Comment: I will just hit up the sysjobsteps table and grab max id....that will work.

Answer (score 1):

will just hit up the sysjobsteps table and grab max id....that will work